# Coldfusion adding extra double-quotes to image path

Tags: image, coldfusion

I built my image paths and did a cfdump to check what is being produced:

```
<!--- Build image paths ---> 
<cfset image_src="../images/f#movie.FilmID#.jpg">
<cfset image_path=ExpandPath(image_src)>
<cfdump var="#image_src#"><br>
<cfdump var="#image_path#">
```

I get the following when I run the page:

```
../images/f5.jpg 
C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\workspace\OWS\images\f5.jpg
```

When I right-click on the image place holder and copy the image URL, what is being passed is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8500/workspace/OWS/10/%E2%80%9D../images/f5.jpg%E2%80%9D
```

so, it is not taking out the ".. and " around the following line as it exands the URL:

```
<cfset image_src="../images/f#movie.filmid#.jpg">
```

On another page I deleted the double-quote and then put them back in and that worked.  For some reason it didn't like the double-quotes that were there to recognize the code correctly.  I can't get that same solution to work here on this page.

Any help/suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: maybe `cfdump` is adding double quotes for you?  Use `cfoutput` instead.

Comment: Is is possible you have "smart quotes" instead of regular quotation marks in your content?

Comment: Henry, no, cfdump isn't producing any double-quotes.

Comment: Will, Yes, that must be what I deleted in the first place, those "smart quotes."  I'm using ColdFusion Builder to write my pages, so I wouldn't know how the code got in there unless I copied it from a web page.  I don't remember doing that though.

After thoroughly looking through the code again for those "smart quotes", I found a few more locations where they were and replaced them.  Page now works.  Thanks for everyone's help!!

Comment: @WillBelden - Since that was the "answer", you should post it as such :) Then jkcrosby3 can close out the thread.

Comment: cflib.org has a function called safetext.  Among other things, it replaces smart quotes with simple quotes.

Comment: Leigh, excuse me if I'm unobservant, but how do you close out a thread?  I couldn't see it immediately and can't seem to find an article on how to do that.  Thanks!

Comment: @jkcrosby3 - You should see a check mark next to each "answer". Click it to mark that answer as "accepted". Note, there may be a slight delay for new members (not sure).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have "smart quotes" instead of regular quotation marks in your content?